# Get records that haven't been updated in over X hours

Tags: laravel, date, eloquent

I am trying to get the records that haven't been updated for over 5 hours

```
where('updated_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subHours(5))->get();
```

But it doesn't seem I'm getting the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be other way around. If record is not updated since 5 hours that means its `updated_at` is smaller than `current_time - 5 hours`.

```
where('updated_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subHours(5))->get();
```

Comment: Gotcha, I just realize that another reason why it's not showing up too is because of the utc time, when using NOW() on the database adds my current time which is ahead of the utc. :)